# Catch-Block doesn't catch Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, try-catch

I am currently working on Windows Forms Project in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile with VS2022. I've got the following code:

```
'sort columns
With Me.dgv02
    Try
        .Columns("Year").DisplayIndex = 0
        ' 27.09.2012:
        '.Columns("OrderID").DisplayIndex = 1 ' 11.09.2013: removed
        Index = 1  ' 11.09.2013
    Catch ex As Exception
        column = "Sum [kg]"
    End Try
End With
```

This is done in a "Backgroundworker_RunWorkerCompleted" event.

If I start the application from Visual Studio with debug, I'll get an `NullReferenceException` because the column "year" doesn't exist. That's basically right, but the catch block doesn't catch it. The execution stops and I'll get the exception message shown, like there is no try... catch...
Even more curious is, that if I start the built exe directly (opening the exe), the catch block works as expected. Can anybody explain to me, what's going on here?

I tried to adapt the catch block to catch specifically the NullReferenceException, but without success.
I expect that the catch block to execute while debugging.

Comment: I've had this issue. I click Continue to get past it. Sometimes I also have to click the check box to ignore such errors in the specific file, which is fine since it's a temporary file anyway.

Comment: It's not that the exception isn't being caught. It's that the debugger is showing you where the exception is thrown first. If you continue then the exception will be caught. You can configure the debugger not to do that for certain or all exceptions if you want, but I'd generally advise against.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So basically you say, that the debugger shows me "Hey, theres an exception", but if I'll hit continue, everything works fine?!

Comment: Check what the debugger says about the exception.  Most likely it will say "exception thrown" rather than "unhandled exception".  You can control how the debugger responds to thrown exceptions by going to Debug - Windows - Exception Settings in Visual Studio.  I'm used to working with apps with a top-level handler, so for me, it's best to default to break-on-throw for everything (selectively disabling for certain modules/exceptions), otherwise I get the app's generic crash message and miss the context for the exception.

Comment: Remember, caught exceptions were still thrown. That's what the debugger is telling you. It's only a problem if the exception is "unhandled".

Comment: *"everything works fine"*. It depends what you mean by that. The code continues to execute as normal, which means it will jump to the `catch` block to catch the thrown exception. It doesn't mean that the code will continue as though the exception wasn't thrown. One reason for this is the fact that, when the debugger breaks, you can change data or execute code, so you might fix the problem that caused the exception and then re-execute the line that threw so it doesn't this time. Seems like the actual problem here is a lack of understanding of how the debugger works.